# How to get a return value from dispatching an action?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

How can I have a return value from dispatching an action?

I have a a createAsyncThunk which fetches a user and sets it to the store:

```
export const initUser = createAsyncThunk('user/initUser', async (_, { dispatch }) => {
  try {
    const user = await API.getUser();
    dispatch(setUser(user));
    return user;
  } catch (e: any) {
    if (e?.status === 404) {
      try {
        const user = await API.createUser();
        dispatch(setUser(user));
        return user;
      } catch (e: any) {
        dispatch(
          showAlert({
            type: AlertType.Error,
            message: 'Some error',
          })
        );
        return Promise.reject(e);
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(e);
  }
});
```

Then I call it in App.tsx:

```
 const signin = useCallback(
    async (token: string) => {
      try {
        await dispatch(initUser());
       // is it okay to do this: const { payload } = await dispatch(initUser());


        if (location.pathname === PATHS.auth) {
          navigate(PATHS.dashboard);
        }
      } catch (e: any) {}
    },
    [location.pathname, dispatch, navigate]
  );
```

How can I get dispatch return value? I mean is it okay to do this in App.tsx inside signin function:

```
const { payload } = await dispatch(initUser());
// do something with payload data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Unwrapping Result Actions](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#unwrapping-result-actions)

> The promise returned by the dispatched thunk has an `unwrap` property which can be called to extract the payload of a fulfilled action or to throw either the error or, if available, payload created by `rejectWithValue` from a rejected action

E.g.

```
const onClick = async () => {
  try {
    const originalPromiseResult = await dispatch(fetchUserById(userId)).unwrap()
    // handle result here
  } catch (rejectedValueOrSerializedError) {
    // handle error here
  }
}
```